# Что такое Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Что такое `Object.prototype` в Javascript?

Comment: Но лучше действительно прочитать документацию :)

http://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: MrFranke ну это даже не документация !Вы хоть бы дали раздел учебника где есть упоминание о объектах....

Comment: Ок :)
http://es5.javascript.ru/x4.html#x4.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это прототип объекта Object. Из него наследуются свойства всеми объектами.
Например:

```
Object.prototype.test = function(){('test!')};
var a = {};
a.test();
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю, что массивы, строки и числа, NaN будут так же наследовать свойство прототипа Object, поведение в принципе не очевидное.